# MVC functionality inside Sharepoint

Tags: mvc

Not sure if this is the best platform to ask, so please advise otherwise...

I've been asked to update an existing ASP.NET MVC application to include some new, but very basic functionality:

- group existing users into "training" groups
- create and schedule "training" events on a calendar widget
- assign groups to events
- upload documents to events

Recently, someone spoke up and said why don't we just build this into our existing MS Sharepoint site...

I don't know much about Sharepoint development, but is this degree of customization possible? Last I checked, you were limited to fixed set of options/widgets when building out a Sharepoint page. Am I missing something? Can I host an MVC application inside a Sharepoint page? What are my options to do something custom like this?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Good question. I will have to ask and report back. What are you thinking?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to ask the person what they meant and how they would approach it. Maybe they didn't know what they were talking about, but maybe they do...

But it's possible given your very high level requirements that you could scrap the MVC app and just build the thing in a SharePoint site using lists and libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Like I said, I'm new to SP. Can list items and libraries be linked together? For example, I need certain documents to ONLY be added and available to certain items in a list. Something that would normally be very easy with an MVC app and relational database. Can that degree of customization be accomplished with SP?

Comment: if you're talking relationships, that's easily accomplished through lookups. If you're talking security, it's not impossible, but something you'll need to think about. The devil is in the details.